# Iptables forwards the port to another IP and adds access restrictions

Tags: iptables, nat

I've added the following rules to iptables.

```bash
-A PREROUTING -p tcp -m tcp --dport 3307 -j DNAT --to-destination 192.168.80.45:330
```

If I want to add a rule to port 3307, for example, to deny access to port 3307 from the 123.5.0.2IP address, how do I configure the iptables rule

Answer (score 0):

One would be tempted to prevent NAT to happen, so in the end the packet would not be forwarded and would stay on the host where without listening service the connection attempt would be reset. This goes against the separation of roles between the firewalling part (*filter* table: the default) and NAT part (*nat* part).

Just add (or insert with `-I` instead of `-A`, depending on already present ruleset) a filtering rule that prevents *forwarded* traffic from 123.5.0.2 to reach 192.168.80.45:330 [sic]:

```
iptables -A FORWARD -s 123.5.0.2 -d 192.168.80.45 -p tcp --dport 330 -j DROP
```

Note that DNAT happened before routing, so the part seen by the filter/FORWARD chain is already destination 192.168.80.45 and TCP port 330 [sic], not 3307. Of course the rule can be made wider and deny every destination port by not stating the protocol and destination port or any destination by not stating the destination address.

There are many other ways to do this. For example if it's important to have the original port 3307 appear in the filter rule instead of the new destination port 330 (eg: because one wants to rewrite separately the NAT rule so the destination shouldn't have to be edited in two places), it's possible by querying *conntrack* like this:

```
iptables -A FORWARD -s 123.5.0.2 -m conntrack --ctproto tcp --ctorigdstport 3307 -j DROP
```

which means: drop forwarded traffic from 123.5.0.2 with protocol TCP and original destination port (before possible DNAT transformation) of 3307.